# Android Cordova onActivityResult not called if started activity taking time in his process by user

Tags: android, cordova, paypal

Here is my flow

Web button **click** -> `Call Js->Call Native plugin->startActivityForResult()` as below:

```
this.cordova.startActivityForResult((CordovaPlugin) this, intent, REQUEST_PAYPAL_PURCHASE);
```

if User do the payment without time wasting then **Native plugin** `onActivityResult()`->**JS call** this work fine

But if User do the payment with taking time more then 1 min then Native plugin `onActivityResult()` not called. I am stuck here I don't know how to getting the result in this above method